# Android custom view can't use alignParentButton or wrap_content

Tags: android, custom-view

I have a problem which I don't know how to solve. I have created a custom view and would like to align it to parrent buttom in a relative layout but when I do that the view gets transparrent?! How can this be?
Also if I set the surrounding views layout_height = wrap_content it fills the whole screen. How can I configure it not to do so but just wrap content?

Here is my custom view

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.LinearGradient;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.Shader;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class HomeMenuBackground extends View
{ 
    private int mScreenWidth;
    private int mScreenHeight;
    private RectF mSpace;
    private RectF mSpaceStroke;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private Paint mPaintStroke;
    private Rect mRect; 
    private LinearGradient mGradient;

    public HomeMenuBackground(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        mScreenWidth = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        mScreenHeight = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        final int mHeighMenu = (int) (mScreenHeight*0.8);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mSpace = new RectF(-20, 2, mScreenWidth + 20, 148);
        mSpaceStroke = new RectF(-22, 0, mScreenWidth + 22, 150);
        mRect = new Rect();

        mPaintStroke = new Paint();
        mPaintStroke.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaintStroke.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaintStroke.setStrokeWidth(2);
        mPaintStroke.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaintStroke = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {       
        mRect.set(0, 75, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        canvas.drawArc(mSpaceStroke, 180, 360, true, mPaintStroke);
        canvas.drawArc(mSpace, 180, 360, true, mPaint);
        canvas.drawRect(mRect, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
    {
        if(mGradient == null)
        {
            mGradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec), Color.WHITE, Color.GRAY, Shader.TileMode.MIRROR);
            mPaint.setShader(mGradient);
        }

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me :D

BR FireFly3000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For deciding the height and width of Custom View you can override [`setMeasuredDimension (int measuredWidth, int measuredHeight)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setMeasuredDimension%28int,%20int%29) method and provide the height, width of view as per your requirement. And I tried with RelativeLayout I can see your Layout at the Bottom with height and width of (100, 100) by using `setMeasuredDimension(100, 100);` inside `onMeasure()` method.

Comment: setMeasuredDimension is marked final but you can override [onMeasure](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)